# what would be a good widget in qt4 for "points"

Tags: qt4

I need to have something like "grid of clickable points". 
It has to be a rectangle, and there has to be possibility to draw a line from one point in rectangle to another one.
I reviewed designer and found nothing. Help me pls :)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to extend QWidget or QPaintDevice and write your own widget. There is nothing out of the box to do this kind of stuff cleanly.

Comment: Maybe you know some other GUI for python which could have it out of the box?